# How to paralellize RDD work when using cassandra spark connector for data aggration?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Here is the sample senario, we have real time data record in cassandra, and we want to aggregate the data in different time ranges. What I write code like below:

```
 val timeRanges = getTimeRanges(report)
 timeRanges.foreach { timeRange =>
          val (timestampStart, timestampEnd) = timeRange

          val query = _sc.get.cassandraTable(report.keyspace, utilities.Helper.makeStringValid(report.scope)).
            where(s"TIMESTAMP > ?", timestampStart).
            where(s"VALID_TIMESTAMP <= ?", timestampEnd)
        ......do the aggregation work....
```

what the issue of the code is that for every time range, the aggregation work is running not in parallized. My question is how can I parallized the aggregation work? Since RDD can't run in another RDD or Future? Is there any way to parallize the work, or we can't using spark connector here?

Answer (score 1):

Use the joinWithCassandraTable function. This allows you to use the data from one RDD to access C* and pull records just like in your example.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#performing-efficient-joins-with-cassandra-tables-since-12

> `joinWithCassandraTable` utilizes the java driver to execute a single
>   query for every partition required by the source RDD so no un-needed
>   data will be requested or serialized. This means a join between any
>   RDD and a Cassandra Table can be preformed without doing a full table
>   scan. When preformed between two Cassandra Tables which share the
>   same partition key this will not require movement of data between
>   machines. In all cases this method will use the source RDD's
>   partitioning and placement for data locality.

Comment: joinWithCassandraTable which will join two tables, but in my code, there is only one source table, range value is generated values.

Comment: It joins 1 RDD to 1 Table. There is no need for the first RDD to be a table.

Comment: What is the actual schema of the table you are trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

Finally , we using union to join each RDD and makes them parallized.